# Create easy alphabetical scrolling in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm looking to emulate the functionality in the latest Music app, namely the nice little cursor that pops up which allows one to scroll super fast to the artist/album/track they're looking for:

[image: "Super Scrolling"]
[image: Regular Scrolling]

Is there a method to enable functionality like this in a `ListView` in the Android SDK?

Comment: please be aware of this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9054

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have your list adapter implement [SectionIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html).  The music app also makes use of [AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) to do some of the heavy lifting. Also use `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` on the actual `ListView` to enable this.

**Edit**: If you're not using a CursorAdapter, you won't be able to use AlphabetIndexer.  You might try looking at the implementation [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.java;h=59b2c2a395f7e737ba142f0d20ce02e08ba35396;hb=HEAD) and seeing how hard it would be to adapt it to work with an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Ok, sweet, but how do I implement `SectionIndexer`? Since my list adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`, how can I get a cursor for it to pass to the `AlphabetIndexer`? I have fairly simple data that I just need to group alphabetically by name, hence the desire to use `AlphabetIndexer`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I'll look into implementing the `SectionIndexer` interface in my adapter and providing my sections.

Comment: sample code: please have look http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is the subclass of ArrayAdapter I'm using. Note that the `objects` I pass in has already been sorted alphabetically, with `Collections.sort(objects)`.

```
class SectionIndexingArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements
        SectionIndexer {

    HashMap<String, Integer> sectionsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> sectionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<Integer> sectionForPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> positionForSection = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public SectionIndexingArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        // Note that List<T> objects has already been sorted alphabetically
        // e.g. with Collections.sort(objects) **before** being passed to
        // this constructor.

        // Figure out what the sections should be (one section per unique
        // initial letter, to accommodate letters that might be missing,
        // or characters like ,)
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            String objectString = objects.get(i).toString();
            if (objectString.length() > 0) {
                String firstLetter = objectString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                if (!sectionsMap.containsKey(firstLetter)) {
                    sectionsMap.put(firstLetter, sectionsMap.size());
                    sectionsList.add(firstLetter);
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate the section for each position in the list.
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            String objectString = objects.get(i).toString();
            if (objectString.length() > 0) {
                String firstLetter = objectString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                if (sectionsMap.containsKey(firstLetter)) {
                    sectionForPosition.add(sectionsMap.get(firstLetter));
                } else
                    sectionForPosition.add(0);
            } else
                sectionForPosition.add(0);
        }

        // Calculate the first position where each section begins.
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionsMap.size(); i++)
            positionForSection.add(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionsMap.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
                Integer section = sectionForPosition.get(j);
                if (section == i) {
                    positionForSection.set(i, j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // The interface methods.

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return positionForSection.get(section);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return sectionForPosition.get(position);
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sectionsList.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works great!!! The only problem I have is that I have an extremely long list... and it takes a long time to get all of the headers... etc... I tried running those for loops in an AsyncTask... but it just froze everything... Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

setFastScrollEnabled(true);

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html)

Answer (score 2):

On anddev.org I found this tutorial: [Alphabetic FastScroll ListView - similar to Contacts](http://www.anddev.org/tutalphabetic_fastscroll_listview_-_similar_to_contacts-t10123.html)

It also contains a short [demo-video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9oi04RMqsc)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

To collect the details about the items shown in a listview, you can do this:

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            albumButton.setText(songs.get(firstVisibleItem).getAlbum());

        }
```

Isn't this a bit simpler? Here, 'songs' is an arraylist of Song objects. You can even get the last visible item by adding firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount. I found this technique to be very useful. So then you would get the first letter of each song. I assume the gray box containing the letter in the music app you posted is a dialog box of sorts?

Anyway, hope this helps. I realise I'm late, but this is for future people

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html?m=1)... Works great with a huge list... Nice and fast... no loading time.

```
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section)
{
    log.info("Get position for section");

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++)
    {
        if (this.getItem(i).length() > 0)
        {
            String item = this.getItem(i).toUpperCase();
            if (item.charAt(0) == sections.charAt(section))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int arg0)
{
    log.info("Get section");

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections()
{
    log.info("Get sections");

    String[] sectionsArr = new String[sections.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < sections.length(); i++)
    {
        sectionsArr[i] = "" + sections.charAt(i);
    }
    return sectionsArr;
}
```