# How to show alphabet list using images on a scroll bar in android

Tags: android, listview

when you scroll to 'B', all the items in the list starting with 'B' should show.
I need to use images for A,B,C etc. Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question, but as far as I understand what you need is fastscroll and alphabetical section.

I think such a question has already been answered here

[Create easy alphabetical scrolling in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122749/create-easy-alphabetical-scrolling-in-listview)