# Alphabetic scrolling like in Contact App

Tags: android

Does anyone know where I can find the source on how to implement the alphabetic scroll bar exactly like the one in the ICS contacts app.

I would like the same look and feel, i.e. the triangular shaped window. I have seen lots of similar examples but none of them look like Google's implementation.

Thanks

i.e. something like this:
[Create easy alphabetical scrolling in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122749/create-easy-alphabetical-scrolling-in-listview)

But I would like Google's version.

Comment: Well its kind of pointy to the left hand side, I can't find a screen shot but its been there since Android 4.0

Comment: Still no idea, maybe not pure android but some manufacturers custom ui? Look at screenshots for ICS+ contacts app, here for example from last year: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/10/18/ics-has-completely-revamped-your-contacts-into-the-people-app/

Comment: This is what I was talking about: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/scrolling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to know google version, is to look at the Contact app  AlphabetIndexer source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-cookbook/source/browse/trunk/OilCan/src/com/android/contacts/AlphabetIndexer.java?r=18)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm going to have to implement my own version since there are no good examples.