# Android: Custom layout for the SectionIndex dialog

Tags: android, indexing

I have a Custom ListView containing events. The Adapters SectionIndexer indexes the day of the week and time of the events upon fastscrolling (e.g. Monday 10:00) but with the default styling of the fastscrolling text, the text is to big and gets cut at the edges.

Is there any way to change the layout of the SextionIndexer dialog? I specifically want to remove the box in the background (or enlarge it to match the day and time displayed) and change the textSize.

There must be a way :) I can't be the only one wanting to index something else than the first letters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you already got your answer but anyway for you and others I found a post about this problem
Take a look at this post [Fast Scroll display problem with ListAdapter and SectionIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225092/fast-scroll-display-problem-with-listadapter-and-sectionindexer)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Although I've already moved on to another project this could come in handy some day. Thanks!