# customizing listview component

Tags: android, listactivity

I am trying to build a list view in android that would look like this (ignore the search-bar):

[image: output.]

iPhone has a similar option called as section index :

[iphone section index. http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcssNycAZ6s_vITQaHXwo3A_pDbfGeQImVdPDPiGn5zCMAR4i_](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcssNycAZ6s_vITQaHXwo3A_pDbfGeQImVdPDPiGn5zCMAR4i_)

I am able to get the sections within the list by using : 
http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Now I want to build the index (something that is on the right of the first image)
(Index is customized and may contain more than just one alphabet)

I don't want to do it the following way :

create an activity that has one listview on left and another textview(or may be anything) on the right then track the right element and update the list.
eg : http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html

I want to customize the listview of android itself so that the list view would include such an index at the right . something like this.
A class that `extends ListActivity` and the class some or how contains the side-bar.
(I'll manage the coding for the side-bar to work). So whenever another class extends `MyCustomListActivity` it will have the list as well as sidebar.

My question is how do I include the side bar in my custom class that is extending the ListActivity ?
Or is there a better approach to doing this ?

Comment: Try adding it to the root view. using `addContentView()`

Comment: @userSeven7s so you mean in `oncreate` of `MyCustomListActivity` I do an `addContentView()` ?

Comment: yes. Otherwise you can add a `PopupWindow` with Gravity.RIGHT.

Comment: I think 1st one seems a better option will try it out and post the results back.

Comment: Rather than inventing a new UI pattern, why not use the existing `SectionIndexer`, which would appear to have the general capability you want and will be familiar to more users?

Comment: cause my index is not just one letter , in a few cases its multiple letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cause my index is not just one letter , in a few cases its multiple
>   letters. – Gaurav Shah 2 days ago

Assuming that's your only reason for not wanting to use Fast Scrolling with `SectionIndexer`, here is some code that's designed to work for [multiple letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225092/fast-scroll-display-problem-with-listadapter-and-sectionindexer).

Here is a screenshot of what it's supposed to look like:

[image: screenshot of a Fast Scrolling ListView using SectionIndexer example using multiple letters]

Comment: I went for another solution ExpandableListView and added scroll as suggested by userSeven7s , lot of other things to consider . But your answer is apt to my question. thanks.