# Can we have a custom scrollbar on an ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview, android-custom-view, fastscroll

I'd like to make a custom scrollbar for one of my scrollview, and impossible to find how to do.

I want my scrollbar to be more visible, and controllable like the fastScroll of the ListViews. Unfortunately there is no setFastScrollEnabled(true) on the ScrollView.

\o/ So say welcome to my two first questions :

**How to change the scrollbar appearence?**

**How to activate fast scrolling on a ScrollView?**

Then another idea come to me : adding buttons and indicators on the scrollbar, as a goToTop and a goToBottom, a progressBar, etc... and so making this little bar an ergonomic tool for users. (for exemple a expandable contextual menu)

So if the first questions have good answers, I've a second step question :

**How to add buttons and setOnClickListener this new ScrollBar?**

To illustrate it :

On the left : FastScroll on ScrollView

On the right : ErgonomicScrollBar on ScrollView

[An image to illustrate it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKMtd.png)

Comment: Possibly [a duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225092/fast-scroll-display-problem-with-listadapter-and-sectionindexer)?

Comment: Not really, I'm talking about ScrollView and not ListView.

Comment: `ScrollView` extends a `FrameLayout`. Modifying a `ScrollView` just means extending the existing `ScrollView` or Creating your own `ScrollView` which extends the `FrameLayout`. This is exactly done in the answer to that question.

Comment: Indeed... it's quite the same thing, it's the same approach. Please answer me your response, i will validate you it.