# Move in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

In my android application, I've a ListView that is loaded with a lot of items. I would like that users could move very fast through the list. I've seen that in some applications, when a list is loaded, and the user starts scrolling, a icon appears on the right of the screen, and this icon can be used to move very fast through the list.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [android:fastScrollEnabled="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3afastScrollEnabled).

Answer (score 0):

See Vardhan's implementation of Fast Scroll for android [here](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-android-listview.html).

> If you want to be able to customize your Fast-scroller, like choosing
>   your own scroller image to appear, I recommend using this source:
>
> https://github.com/nolanlawson/CustomFastScrollViewDemo/
>
> Basically, your listview adapter will have to implement a
>   sectionindexer. This section indexer can be very stripped if you don't
>   want to complicate things and provide simple fastscrolling though the
>   entire length of the list.
>
> The direct source for the fastscroller is here:
>
> https://github.com/nolanlawson/CustomFastScrollViewDemo/blob/master/src/com/nolanlawson/customfastscrollviewdemo/CustomFastScrollView.java
>
> Place this view around your listview (nest your listview inside this
>   view in your xml layout file) and set android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
>   on your listview.
>
> You might also want to check out a previous answer:
>   [Fast Scroll display problem with ListAdapter and SectionIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225092/fast-scroll-display-problem-with-listadapter-and-sectionindexer)

Source : [How to use fast scroll in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374830/how-to-use-fast-scroll-in-android)