# How to enable fast scrolling for a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, fastscroll

I use a fragment activity to hold a list fragment which renders a bunch of products:

```
public class ProductsListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_products_list);
        // setFastScrollEnabled(true) ?
    }
}
```

...

```
<!-- fragment_products_list.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.example.fragment.ProductsListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

...

```
public class ProductsListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // setFastScrollEnabled(true) ?
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to [enable fast scrolling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29) for the list of products and found another post which describes [how to do this for a list activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375023/356895). But how can I activate fast scrolling for the fragment? It would be okay to [define this in XML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled) or via code.

Comment: Why not use getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true) inside the SherlockListFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **SherlockListFragment** also has a `getListView()` method **inherited from ListFragment.**

```
getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

This is how it could look like inside your `ListFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) strings.add("Item " + i);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
}
```