# How to make Touchable and Movable Scroll Bar in a List View

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, scrollbar, sectionindexer

I have created a List View, which contains a bulk amount of data. [Traditional Scrolling](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/scrolling.html#indicator) is quite slow.

I would like to create the scroll view touchable, so that the user can touch the scroll bar and move it to any position, so as to scroll through the list quickly. So, is there any way to make the scroll bar draggable to any position in the list.

One way of doing it (what I can think of) is to use [Section Indexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html)

> Interface that should be implemented on Adapters to enable fast
>   scrolling in an AbsListView between sections of the list. A section is
>   a group of list items to jump to that have something in common. For
>   example, they may begin with the same letter or they may be songs from
>   the same artist.

But the List I'm populating in this case is not necessarily sorted in any order(not even in alphabetical order). So, is there any other efficient way of implementing draggable Scroll View in the ListView

Comment: why don't you use `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` in your listview ?

Comment: @Sunny I want to scroll by touching and dragging the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look here : https://github.com/nolanlawson/CustomFastScrollViewDemo

you can also look at others similar posts : [Fast Scroll display problem with ListAdapter and SectionIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225092/fast-scroll-display-problem-with-listadapter-and-sectionindexer)

good luck