# Alphabet Indexing in Listview.. Ignore Section Indexing

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I've successfully implemented the Indexing as below using. I know about section header, So need of that.
 
http://spinettaro.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-snippet-code-android-listview.html 
[image]

My requirement is to customized it as in Android Jellybean Contact list like below 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3225092/1056359

Comment: @thepoosh I've that type of code I need customized code as in Android 4.2. i.e. I posted seperately

Comment: you're still trying to create a custom view for the different sections? if not, try to explain what the question is

Comment: @thepoosh - Image is updated.. That is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Is [this what you want](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/)? I personaly have found this tutorial very helpfull! You can try [this one as well](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440).

***Edit***:
This [GitHub project](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter) is good to get you started as well.

For the highlighting you can try [this](http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html). I havent tried it, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: This is section indexing of List View.. I need the as in desired image, like "N" must be as in image highlighted one.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I failed to understand your question. I haven't tried this one, but could you look into it? (My edits look messy as I'm not very used to it yet)